The speed of a QM particle
In the original theory of quantum mechanics what is the speed of quantum particles, I am asking this because photons can only travel at the speed of light C. What about mass particles?

Well, particles with mass have momentum (the momentum operator), so getting the velocity is straightforward.

Your QM text should remind you that $\vec v= -i \hbar\langle \nabla \rangle/m $ .

Mass particles can travel at any speed (so long as it is less than that of light) depending on how much energy was invested in accelerating them.
